# Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
    import Home from './pages/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return ( 
    <Routes>
    <div className="max-w-screen-md mx-auto pt-20">
     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    </div>
    </Routes>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Already i have many research and install many npm base code , but facing same problem (Error: A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your  in a ).

Thanks and love from my heart for advanced.

Comment: Hi, i experimented the same problem, it is just because, the code reference used, it is from a date let say one year ago, and the router-dom project did rules changes in the component design, so, it does not work thus anymore.

i reverted the dependency in the package.json, from the nowdays, set by the npm command: npm install --save react-router-dom, which today is "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2"

and i used the older, from the git repo where the tutorial had set on the dependency version wich really supports that implementation  

    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"

Comment: this is the repository   https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application/blob/master/client/src/App.js

it is like the one you are trying, navigate the repo, two levels above, and confirm the version dependency in the package.json

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import { BrowserRouter as Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

You're importing BrowserRouter and renaming it to Routes. This isn't the component that is mentioned in the error message. Instead, you need to import BrowserRouter *and also* import Routes and use it.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="max-w-screen-md mx-auto pt-20">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```